# Unable to Insert into database

Tags: python, mysql, insert, mysql-python

I want to insert data into the database using following script.There can be 3 suppliers and with respect to each of them I need to store the Warehouse state and zip code .

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys,os
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import time


WEBAPP_CONSTANTS = {
'LOGFILE': '/home/ai/Desktop/home/ubuntu/LCF/Database/db.log',
}
def getWebAppConstants(constant):
     return WEBAPP_CONSTANTS.get(constant, False)

LOGFILE = getWebAppConstants('LOGFILE')
log_handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOGFILE, maxBytes=1048576, backupCount=5)
log_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter( '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s ' '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
applogger = logging.getLogger("DB")
applogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
applogger.addHandler(log_handler)
applogger.debug("Starting of Database")
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
completeName = os.path.abspath("/home/ai/Desktop/home/ubuntu/LCF/Database/out.txt")
f = file(completeName, 'w')
sys.stdout = f


try:
    con = mdb.connect('*********', '********', '*******', '****')
    cur = con.cursor()
    con.autocommit(True)

except mdb.Error, e: 
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

def databaseinsert(id1,data):
    print "entered database insert with",id1,"and",data
    if id1=="1" or id1=="3":
        for i in data:
            print i
            print "entered with ",id1
            print i[0],i[1]
            d=i[0]
            d1=i[1]
            cur.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM d_supplier_warehouse WHERE d_supplier_warehouse.state = %s AND d_supplier_warehouse.zipcode= %s) ",(d,d1))
            print "repeat check"
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            print "fetched rows"
            if rows[0][0]==1:
                print "same"
                continue
            else:
                print "successful entry"
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO d_supplier_warehouse (supplier_id,state,zipcode) Values(%s,%s,%s)",(id1,d,d1))
                print "completed"
    if id1=="2":
        print "entered with 2"
        d=data[0];d1=data[1]
        print d,d1
        cur.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM d_supplier_warehouse WHERE d_supplier_warehouse.state = %s AND d_supplier_warehouse.zipcode= %s )",(d,d1))
        print "repeat check"
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        print "fetched rows"
        if rows[0][0]==1:
            print "same"
            pass
        else:
            print "successful entry"
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO d_supplier_warehouse (supplier_id,state,zipcode) Values(%s,%s,%s)",(id1,d0,d1))
            print "completed"
```

The out.txt I am getting is :

```
entered database insert with 1 and [('GA', '30024', '0', '77.3'), ('MI', '49544', '0', '77.3'), ('MA', '01801', '6', '77.3'), ('CA', '91749', '13', '77.3'), ('MD', '21076', '28', '77.3'), ('TN', '37086', '2', '77.3'), ('OH', '44087', '6', '77.3'), ('MN', '55121', '5', '77.3'), ('IL', '62246', '1', '77.3'), ('NY', '12051', '13', '77.3'), ('MO', '64116', '8', '77.3'), ('OR', '97203', '10', '77.3'), ('OK', '74116', '0', '77.3'), ('WA', '98188', '3', '77.3'), ('IL', '60188', '13', '77.3'), ('TX', '75061', '14', '77.3'), ('AZ', '85282', '0', '77.3'), ('FL', '33178', '1', '77.3'), ('OH', '43228', '10', '77.3'), ('IN', '46268', '0', '77.3'), ('TN', '38141', '8', '77.3'), ('TX', '77040', '5', '77.3'), ('CA', '95842', '9', '77.3'), ('UT', '84104', '0', '77.3'), ('NJ', '08512', '10', '77.3'), ('CO', '80238', '3', '77.3'), ('FL', '32819', '17', '77.3'), ('NC', '28278', '14', '77.3')]
('GA', '30024', '0', '77.3') 
entered with  1
GA 30024
entered database insert with 2 and ('MO', '63042', '11', '72.82')
entered with 2
MO 63042
entered database insert with 3 and [('CA', '94538', '1', '72.84'), ('GA', '30071', '1', '72.84'), ('TX', '75081', '6', '72.84'), ('IL', '60446', '3', '72.84'), ('MS', '38654', '2', '72.84'), ('NJ', '08831', '9', '72.84'), ('VA', '20151', '0', '72.84'), ('OR', '97008', '0', '72.84'), ('CA', '91761', '1', '72.84'), ('OH', '43123', '2', '72.84'), ('FL', '33182', '4', '72.84')]
('CA', '94538', '1', '72.84') 
entered with  3
CA 94538
```

which clearly shows that the code is not going to completion . And as a result my database is not being filled.

How to solve this and what is the reason behind the not pushing of data to database ?

Comment: Can you show the part of the code where you are calling the function `databaseinsert` and if possible, provide us the inputs you are providing to this function

Comment: id1 and data are the inputs to the function which are being shown in out.txt .

Comment: However I don't think that providing the part of code where `databaseinsert` is being called will help in any way as the code base is too large and complicated.

Comment: The need for using the `Exists` in the query `cur.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM d_supplier_warehouse WHERE d_supplier_warehouse.state = %s AND d_supplier_warehouse.zipcode= %s) ",(d,d1))` is not very clear as you are not using the output from this query any where in your function. And, one more thing, how are you handling the exception when this query fails ?

Comment: I am using the `EXISTS` query to check for the uniqueness in the database .

Comment: @TusharMakkar Using `EXISTS` prior to `INSERT` to check uniqueness is _not_ a good idea. For example, what will append if two concurrent transactions try to add the same row? Each one will succeed on its side. And you end up with a duplicate in your db... The _right_ solution is to add a _unique index_ somehow and let `INSERT` (or `COMMIT` depending your db engine and/or transaction isolation level) fail in case of duplicate.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to explain your business rules clearly.  It's difficult for us to try to figure them out from your code. At the same time you're having trouble with that part of your code, it seems. For example, is your system limited to one supplier warehouse per state and zip code?

Comment: You're using autocommit, but you're also doing explicit commits.  That's redundant. Also, please explain the ten-second sleep between issuing a query and reading the resultset.

Comment: All that stuff was redundant .. I was using them to check whether or not the error was due to commiting or not.. Edited the question